# Retrieving stdout/stderr on Amazon EBS

Tags: node.js, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I get what has been printed to stdout/stderr (using `console.log` and `console.warn` with Node.js EC2 Instance) using Amazon AWS, specifically EBS?

Comment: How do you run your server? how do you start node? You could look-up [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), it's very useful.

Comment: I'm using the default configuration for 64-bit Node.js Application in Elastic Beanstalk.

I also have a stack setup in OpsWorks for a second 64-bit Node.js Application.